# Disable bell in MacVim

Tags: vim, notifications, macvim

I know this topic has been asked multiple times. But I don't seem to be able to disable the acoustic bell in MacVim. What I have in my .vimrc:

```
set noerrorbells 
set novisualbell
set t_vb=
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This should be the missing piece:

```
autocmd! GUIEnter * set vb t_vb=
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I finally ```set visualbell t_vb=``` to disable it in both vim and MacVim. After re-reading ```help``` it clearly states what you proposed. Seems like I missed it over and over again.

Comment: one question, macVim==Gui vim? know nothing about Mac. what is the vim in Mac terminal (iTerminal? ) called? not macVim?

Comment: Yes, MacVim is a GUI version for Mac, just like GVim for Linux. You can symlink/alias the binary (MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim) in the MacVim.app package which is plain vim in the terminal then.

Comment: @Kent, MacVim == Gvim. It comes with a CLI executable that one can run in the shell, though.

Comment: I thought all vim in mac are called macVim...I am wrong.  upvote your answer to say thank you.... @Ube thank you too...

Comment: Additionally it ships a script ```mvim``` which lets you open files from the terminal in MacVim.

Answer (score 4):

Vim: `set belloff = all` in your `.vimrc`

NeoVim: `vim.opt.belloff = "all"` in your `options.lua` - `"all"` is the default value, see `:h belloff` for relative options in docs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26264362)

Comment: @RobScott This setting in my .vimrc disable with success the acoustic bell. I don't want to make any criticism. Anyway thanks for your words.

Comment: @Joaness - Understood. The answer was flagged by SO (and therefore displayed in the "for review" edits). SO will automatically enter that default comment, based on the decision I entered. My apologies for accepting the flag, as it was in the category of "questionable answers", based on the length of characters. When answering an old post especially, include updated docs and/or version updates and/or explaination(s) for why your newly posted answer is correct.

Comment: @RobScott I agree. Thanks! I was on the subject in the past few days and had found this solution that seems to work. I happened on this question today and in a hurry I wrote a few words. It won't happen again.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that for some reason couldn't make this work.

`set vb t_vb=     " no visual bell & flash`

did the job for me.